# Determine the rank of a matrix given its nullspace

Tags: linear-algebra

In the book ***Introduction to Linear Algebra*** of Gilbert Strang, there is a question:
"If $Nullspace(A) =$ all multiples of $x = (2,1,0,1)$. What is the reduced row echelon form of A and what is its rank?"

In the solution, the author wrote:

"If $N(A) =$ line through $x = (2, 1, 0, 1)$, A has three pivots (4 columns and 1 special solution). Its reduced echelon form can be R =
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 &-2 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
(and can add zero rows) "

However, I see that R can also be:
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & -1 & 0 &-1 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
and in this case, A only has rank 1.

***My question is what is the correct answer? And if the solution of the book is true, why can we conclude that A has three pivots given its nullspace = line through x =(2,1,0,1) ?***

Thank you all!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: In the second case, the nullity of $A$ is $3$.

Answer (score 1):

According to the rank-nullity theorem, $\text{rank}(A)+\dim\ker(A)=\dim V$, where $V$ is the domain of the linear transformation. We need $$\text{rank}(A)=\dim V-1$$If the domain of $A$ is entire $\Bbb R^4,\text{rank}(A)=3$. Thus the rows of $A$ comprise of three linearly independent vectors in $\Bbb R^4$ orthogonal to $x$ and their linear multiples. Note that $A$ may have any number of rows $\ge3$.

Your solution could be correct, but you need to then specify why $\text{rank}(A)=1$ is a valid choice. You need $\dim V=2$, i.e. the domain of $A$ is not entire $\Bbb R^4$ but a $2$-dimensional subspace $S$ of $\Bbb R^4$. Moreover, a basis of $S$ contains $x$ and a vector $v\in\Bbb R^4$ orthogonal to $x$. One candidate is $v=(1,-1,0,-1)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, for the second part of your answer, I think that R^2 is not a subspace of R^4.

Comment: He has not said that $R^2$ is a subspace of $R^4$ but rather that you need to consider a subspace of $R^4$ which is two-dimensional, which can always be found as subspaces have a dimension less than or equal to the parent vector space.

Comment: @DucThinhVu The linear span of $(1,-1,0,-1)$ and $(2,1,0,1)$ is a $2$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^4$

Answer (score 0):

It's a given that the null space of $A$ is $span(x), x=(2,1,0,1)$. Therefore, $Ax=0$, where $0$ is the zero vector.

Hence, $A$ must have $4$ columns, my the matrix multiplication rule.

Now the maximal column rank of $A$ is $4$.
Since the nullity if $A$ is $1$, column rank of $A = 4-1 = 3 =$ Row rank of $A$

Hence, the matrix must have $3$ rows.